# $.getJSON won't work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When I click the button, I get nothing.. My code below. Thanks in advance for any help. I've tried so many different methods and none of it works at all.

I think maybe there is an error in my JQuery but I cannot find it. Or my JSON file syntax.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head><title>JSON Practice</title>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20140204/json2.min.js"></head>
<body>

<ul></ul>
<button>Users</button>

<script src="script/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery:

```
$("button").click( function() {
$.getJSON('json_data.json', function(obj) { 
$.each(obj, function(key, value) { 
     $("ul").append("<li>"+value.name+"</li>");
  });
 });
});
```

JSON:

```
{
   "p1": { 
              "name": "Satish",
              "age":   25,
              "company": "Techntoip"
          },


   "p2": {
              "name": "Kiran",
              "age":   28,
              "company": "Oracle"   
          }                          
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on a server?

Comment: What errors, if any, do you see in your JS console? ( [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) )

Comment: where is json_data.json in relation to my_script.js? is it in the same directory?

Comment: EDIT: I fixed it guys, it was an amateur error. My JSON file was incorrectly named and I AM running it on a server.